# Django and requests JSON response

Tags: python, django

How do I get JSON response in django using requests library? I currently have something of the following form:

```
    def predict(self, form):
        image = form.instance.input_image
        image_data = bytes(image.read())
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
        data_dict = {'input': np.array(img).tolist()}
        data = requests.post(
            'http://localhost:5000/predict', json=data_dict)
        return JsonResponse({'prediction': list(data)})
```

but this just returns `<Response [200]>` and the error `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your problem, but:

first thing:

```
data = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/predict', data=json.dumps(data_dict))
```

then, if you want requests response as json, simply:

```
data.json()
```

Comment: Printing `data.json()` outputs only `<bound method Response.json of <Response [500]>>`

Comment: Are you sure you print(data.json()), not print(data.json)?

Comment: I should get more sleep :)

Comment: Funny. Made the very same mistake and your comments here helped me. Thanks!